# Automatically changing the opportunity owner to account owner?

Tags: opportunity, automation, ownership, record-owner

I am rather newly certified Salesforce Admin, and I am trying to solve an issue in my org that I just can't get my head around. I hope you can help.

What I have been asked to do is create an automation, which automatically changes the opportunity owner to the related account owner when the opportunity is moved into closed won or closed lost. 
At first I thought this might be doable with a workflow rule, but it seems impossible. Can anyone help me out here?

All the best, 
Jonas

Answer (score 2):

Use the Process Builder. First, go to Setup > Process Builder (find it in Quick Find). Create a new Process that starts when a record is updated. Choose Opportunity as the object, for the first criteria, choose when Conditions are met, and enter your criteria (suggested: Closed/equals/Boolean/true). Next, add an immediate action to update the record that started the process, with field update as Owner Id/Field Reference/[Opportunity].Account.OwnerId. Finally, activate it and test it out.

---

[image: Select Opportunity]

---

[image: Add Criteria]

---

[image: Add Immediate Action]